# Python 3: gtk.gdk.window_foreign_new doesn't exist

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to convert a script from python2.7 to python3. The function gtk.gdk.window_foreign_new return a gtk.gdk.Window object. I tryed to use the function GdkX11.X11Window.foreign_new_for_display but return "class 'gi.repository.GdkX11.X11Window'". Instead, I need a window object for the code to work.
I need help.

Comment: I haven't got any experience of calling Gdk.Window directly, but I believe this is now a Window Attribute - see [Gdk.Window](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gdk-3.0/classes/Window.html#Gdk.Window), [Gdk.WindowAttr](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gdk-3.0/classes/WindowAttr.html#Gdk.WindowAttr) `window_type` field for more info

Comment: I do not think this is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

It is the equivalent for GTK3: `GdkX11.X11Window` is a subclass of `Gdk.Window`, it is a window object, see
[X11Window](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/GdkX11-3.0/classes/X11Window.html)
Perhaps the problem is with your code? What is your problem with this window instance?